# How to execute a method automatically after entering Qt event loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, pyqt4, event-loop

I would like to execute a method which can only be called once my `QApplication` is displayed, i.e. when it has entered its main event loop `exec_()`. I'm new to Qt4 (using PyQt4): i was hoping to have a `on_start()`-like callback, but didn't find one.
Do i need to create a thread or a timer? Or is there some callback included in the API already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i have chosen to use `QThread` this way:

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
    ''' reinplemented from parent '''
        # make thread sleep to make sure
        # QApplication is running before doing something
        self.sleep(2)
        do_something()

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.attr = 'foo'
        self.thread = MyThread(self)
        self.thread.start()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works for my purpose because my thread in my (real) code actually looks for the application window in X display and will try doing so until it finds it. But otherwise that's not an elegant way to solve the problem.
It would be nicer if there was a signal emitted by `QApplication` when entering the event-loop. JAB proposed the [Qt.ApplicationActivate](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qevent.html#Type-enum) but it doesn't seem to be emitted by `QApplication`, and even if it was, because the `MyWidget()` is not instantiated as a child of `QApplication`, i wouldn't know how to pass the signal from `app` to `w`

I'll wait for a better answer, if any, before accepting my answer as the chosen solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a single-shot timer for this, as in the following simple script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

def on_start():
    print(' in event loop!')
    print(' telling app to exit ...')
    app.exit(123)

QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, on_start)
print('About to enter event loop')
rc = app.exec_()
print('All done - returned %d' % rc)
```

when you run this, you should see

```
About to enter event loop
 in event loop!
 telling app to exit ...
All done - returned 123
```

Comment: ha thanks, i thought of using QTimer too. I chose for [QThread](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html) eventually, which i thought was more simple to use. But your example makes it more clear than the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Qt before, so I might be wrong on this, but I imagine you could bind your `on_start()` method to the `ApplicationActivate` event, and set a flag from inside your `on_start()` method so that the code would only be run that very first time and not any other times the `ApplicationActivate` event is triggered during execution of your program.

On the other hand if the `on_start()` method would be called by multiple threads, you might want to use thread-specific flags. Haven't done much multithreading myself, so I'm not sure of what the specifics for that would be, or how simple/complicated it would be.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I've seen the [`Qt.ApplicationActivate`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qevent.html#Type-enum) but i remain confused because the [`QApplication`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qapplication.html) does not have that signal implemented. If i have to bind this signal to `QApplication`, it would have to take place after the event loop has started too, which brings me back to my initial problem. But perhaps i am just not understanding how signals work in Qt :)

Comment: "but i remain confused because the QApplication does not have that signal implemented." That's what subclassing is for.

Comment: @JAB: Yep i thought of that in the time between my comment and yours. But then can the event of `QApplication` be passed to `QWidget` even as it the latter is not the child of the former? I've seen event-handling between children of or with the topmost widget only.

Comment: I think it should be possible, but as I said I don't have any experience actually using Qt. http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#notify

Comment: @JAB: ha! perhaps i can connect the `Widget()` instance to the `QApplication` outside the Widget() class definition, i.e. in the `main()` function. I'll try and let you know how it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @JAB: despite information asserting the contrary, or if indeed the event is emitted after the main loop is entered, the event posted with the [`postEvent()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) method is released at a point when the window is yet not displayed. So i stick to QThread.

Comment: @Benjamin: Even if you use `QtEvent.WindowActivate` rather than `QtEvent.ApplicationActivate`?